# Access shared data with handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

In my Android project, I have a class in which I registered a BroadcastReceiver:

```
public MyClass {
     private MyData mData;

     public MyClass(Context context) {
        mData = GET_PERSISTED_DATA(); 
        //code to register receiver
        ...
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
     }

     public void accessData() {
        //Code to access mData
        ...
     }

     private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver=  new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                    //This is called in main UI thread
                    accessData();
             }

}
```

As you see above, in `onReceive()` of `myReceiver`, it calls `accessData()` method to access `mData`.  **However**, there is **another worker thread** (other than main thread) could also call `accessData()` method. Which means it is **not** thread safe.

Since [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) handles messages one by one from message queue, could I use an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the following way to make above case thread-safe? Or is there a more elegant way?

```
public MyClass {
         private MyData mData;
         private Handler mHandler;

         public MyClass(Context context) {
            mData = GET_PERSISTED_DATA(); 
            //code to register receiver
            ...
            context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
            mHandler = new MyHandler();
         }

         public void accessData() {
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(1));
         }

         private class MyHandler extends Handler() {
             @Override
             void handleMessage(Message msg){
                 if(msg.what == 1){
                    //Code to access mData
                     ...
                 }

             }
         }

         private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver=  new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                        //This is called in main UI thread
                        accessData();
                 }

    }
```

Am I thread safe now by using handler in above way?

Answer (score 0):

If the method accessData() is fast, then just declare it as synchronized. If it is long-running, then, besides declaring it synchronized, take care of the thread it is running on when called from onReceive(), because by default onReceive () is called on the main (UI) thread, and this thread cannot be occupied for a long time. How to execute long-running work outside the main thread is described elsewhere.

APPEND:
your implementation may work, but has some pitfalls: the thread which actually do the work caused by accessData() is the thread which has executed the constructor of MyClass. First, this is bad design: the initializing thread may change, and the program can cease to work because the new  thread may have no Looper. Then, the initializing thread is the UI thread, this means that even the worker thread delegates the work to the UI thread when normally UI thread must be freed from any non-UI work.

Handlers and Loopers are not universal means which should be used whenever possible. First learn the basics of multithreaded programming and you'll find that you can live without them.

Comment: Thanks, but I would also like to know is it thread-safe by using handler in the way I posted?